# How to Integrate INDIRECT with SUMIFS

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have several sheets of customers in excel, In summary sheet I want to show sale between date range,
'''

```
=SUMIFS('Riaz Haider'!$B$5:$B$71,'Riaz Haider'!$A$5:$A$71,">="&B3,'Riaz Haider'!$A$5:$A$71,"<="&D3)
```

It is working properly but as you notice here I have used sheet name.

But I want to incorporate cell no for example A5 instead of sheet name, as I have all sheet names on summary sheet. As per my knowledge here we have to use INDIRECT but unfortunatly without success, if any body can help me to resolve it. Please.

Comment: hi can you explain why you say instead of sheet name? What you show has both sheet name and cell references. Please edit question to say what you want to do with A5, and show what you have tried or we cannot understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indirect() creates a reference from a text string. If you want to use it, you need to make sure that what is between the brackets of Indirect() is a valid reference.

If you have a sheet name in cell A5 and you always want to look at rows 5 to 71 in columns A and B of that sheet, then you can combine the text in A5 with the text for the cell references.

So, instead of `'Riaz Haider'!$B$5:$B$71` you can use

`Indirect("'"&A5&"'!$B$5:$B$71")`

Remember that sheet names with spaces need to be wrapped in single quotes. This makes the start of the Indirect string a bit more complex.

```
=SUMIFS(Indirect("'"&A5&"'!$B$5:$B$71"),Indirect("'"&A5&"'!$a$5:$a$71"),">="&B3,Indirect("'"&A5&"'!$a$5:$a$71"),"<="&D3)
```